# Can we regenerate subgraph from the supergraph in GraphQL/Apollo Federation?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, federation

I need to know Is that possible or not.
For example we have 3 api and each have their subgraph and we have implemented federation.
By Using federation we have created Single Truth of Source that is Supergraph.
Now I want to regenerate All 3 Subgraphs by using Supergraph.